# onclick not working in external js-file, but in inline

Tags: javascript, onclick

**What I want** : change text-color to red on text in a `<h1>`tag with `<id="headline">`

Anyone that has an idea why the following code does not work, but further down in this question, that code work by moving onclick-event to inline code?

**Does not work** : following code written in external js-file

```
function changeColor(){
    document.getElementById("headline").style.color = "red";
}

document.getElementById("headline").onclick = changeColor;
```

---

**Works** : Following code written in external js-file (function is the same):

```
function changeColor(){
    document.getElementById("headline").style.color = "red";
}
```

…and this written in inline code:

```
<h1 id="headline"  onclick="changeColor()">with inline code this text change color on click</h1>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? Does it appear after the element? if not is it wrapped in window.onload?

Comment: Works fine in JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Wm6Qv/

Comment: As @bpeterson76 said, it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Yes an error in console. Console says  document.getElementById(...) is null. (beginner to js, but know now what console is, had to googled it :) ). Still don't know what the error means though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing more of your code, I would assume that you are creating and binding the `changeColor()` function in a javascript file that is loaded in the `<head>` of your HTML.

If so, the element with id headline doesn't exist yet (the javascript file is being processed before the HTML has fully loaded), so you are trying to bind to a non-existent element.

If this is the case, either move your script include to the bottom of the `<body>` element , or  wrap the binding in a `window.onload` function as seen in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/winterblood/Wm6Qv/2/).

Comment: All presumptions conformed. So your tip worked lovely, thanks a lot!

Comment: still works in 2021, thanks for the tip. This has been a bane of mine for w3 modals. Your script works like a charm.