# How to slowly enlarge image with javascript onmouseover

Tags: javascript, html

Only Javascript , no jQuery!

HTML:

```
<div class="mid">
    <img onmouseover="lielaBilde(this)" onmouseout="mazaBilde(this)" src="bilde.png" alt="bilde"/>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function lielaBilde(x) {
x.style.height = "121px";
x.style.width = "181px";
}

function mazaBilde(x) {
x.style.height = "121px";
x.style.width = "121px";
}
```

I want to create so that my img increases from 121px to 182px overtime. For example in 3 seconds slowly zooming in. At the moment it's just instant enlarging.

Comment: you should consider using CSS transitions, and use javascript only to add/remove a class

Comment: You could use CSS3 Transitions

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by simply adding css no need to add any javascript or jQuery for it.

```
.mid{
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 background: #222;
 -webkit-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
 -moz-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
 -o-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
 -ms-transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
 transition: width 2s ease, height 2s ease;
}

.mid:hover {
 width: 121px;
 height: 181px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS as shown below.

```
.mid img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s;
    transition: width 2s, height 2s
}
.mid img:hover {
    width: 181px;
    height: 181px;
}
```

No Javascript needed.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Nitsan Baleli, you can use CSS transition. Additionally, CSS also supports :hover selector thus giving this a bit more easy to do.

HTML:

```
<div class="mid>
    <img src="bilde.png" alt="bilde"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.mid img:hover {
   transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function lielaBilde(x) {
var pos=121;
 var id = setInterval(frame, 3);
 function frame() {
    if (pos == 181) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++; 
      x.style.height= pos + 'px'; 
      x.style.width= pos + 'px'; 
    }
  }

}
```

Try this for mouseover. Pure javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()`

```js
function lielaBilde(x) {
  var height, width;
  myVar = setInterval(function(){
    height = parseInt(x.style.height);
    width = parseInt(x.style.width)+1;

    x.style.height = height + "px";
    x.style.width = width + "px";
    if(width==181)
      clearInterval(myVar);
  }, 50);
  
}

function mazaBilde(x) {
  clearInterval(myVar);
  x.style.height = "121px";
  x.style.width = "121px";
}
```

```html
<div class="mid">
    <img onmouseover="lielaBilde(this)" onmouseout="mazaBilde(this)" src="http://placehold.it/121" alt="bilde" style="height:121px; width:121px"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working... so May be your function is not working because

1 - You are giving wrong path of your js file.

2 - Your Function is in the `head` tag. In this case you need to move your JavaScript after the `body` tag see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17437278/2724173)

```js
function lielaBilde(x) {
  x.style.height = "121px";
  x.style.width = "181px";
}

function mazaBilde(x) {
  x.style.height = "121px";
  x.style.width = "121px";
}
```

```html
<div class="mid">
  <img onmouseover="lielaBilde(this)" onmouseout="mazaBilde(this)" src="http://placehold.it/121x121" alt="bilde" />
</div>
```

Comment: i personally prefer to use css hover instead of js as other said.

Answer (score 0):

You can set css3 properties in your function...

```
function lielaBilde(x) {
x.style.WebkitTransition = 'width 3s ease';
x.style.MozTransition = 'width 3s ease';
x.style.height = "121px";
x.style.width = "181px";
}
```